# DNSSEC sign-zone results in fatal failure

Tags: domain-name-system, dnssec, keys

I have a working DNS in a VM-env for testing and learning purposes.
It's a complete server from root-domain and a couple of subdomains.

I've added

```
dnssec-enable yes;
```

into named.conf, and also created the ZSV- and KSK-keys and appended them to one of my subdomains.

I'm trying to take the easy path and only signing one domain. Let's say I have

```
home.garage.top
```

as my top- and subdomains, and I want to sign home, and only home. I use

```
dnssec-signzone -o home.db -N increment -k Khome.garage.top.+005+46921 home.db Khome.garage.top.+005+36051
```

This should produce a home.db.signed or home.signed but it does not. All I get is

```
dnssec-signzone: error: dns_master_load: home.db:10: home.garage.top: not at top of zone
dnssec-signzone: fatal: failed loading zone from 'home.db': not at top of zone
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are specifying that the origin is `home.db` (using `-o`). Is that actually the name of the zone, it sounded like the name of the zone was rather `home.garage.top`?

That kind of mismatch would fit the kind error message you're getting.

As a general suggestion regarding DNSSEC and BIND, however, I would suggest making use of the built-in functionality for zone maintenance rather than calling `dnssec-signzone` manually (and scheduling that somehow).

See the [`auto-dnssec maintain` and possibly `inline-signing yes` settings](http://ftp.isc.org/isc/bind9/cur/9.10/doc/arm/Bv9ARM.ch06.html#id2595259) as well as [this guide](https://deepthought.isc.org/article/AA-00711/0/In-line-Signing-With-NSEC3-in-BIND-9.9-A-Walk-through.html).

Comment: Thanks. That got rid of the "top of zone"-message. Not it seems like the key file (ZSV) cannot be found. I'll try to handle that on my own. Thanks a lot.