# DNSSEC key-file not found

Tags: domain-name-system, debian-wheezy, dnssec

This is actually a follow-up on my previous question (my problem was solved) it can be found here:
[DNSSEC sign-zone results in fatal failure](https://serverfault.com/questions/655097/dnssec-sign-zone-results-in-fatal-failure)

However, I still want to use `dnssec-signzone` when creating my signed zone file.

After I corrected the syntax to

```
dnssec-signzone -o home.garage.top -N increment -k Khome.garage.top.+005+46921 home.db Khome.garage.top.+005+36051
```

I get the following output

```
dnssec-signzone: fatal: cannot load dnskey Khome.garage.top.+005+36051: file not found
```

I know what it implies, but I can't wrap my head around it. I've tried to append the keys to `home.db`and I've also tried to include them in `named.conf. The permissions on the file also looks ok

```
-rw-r--r--  root  bind
```

When I did the includes I used an absolute path to the files i.e `/etc/bind/keyfile`, they are located in the same directory as the db-file. Might not be best practice but unless that is an issue I'll let them stay right where they are until I get it working.

It looks as the KSK is found, but the ZSK is not.

I'll also include the contents of the files

KSK == `home.garage.top IN DNSKEY 257 3 5 "keyhash"`

ZSK == `home.garage.top IN DNSKEY 256 3 5 "keyhash"`

The commented activation dates in these files are December 27, so I take it that won't be a problem either.

Any suggestions, or should I try to redo the keys and start over?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I managed to solve this at last, with some minor help by a friend (he's hard to reach around x-mas and surrounding days).

It is, apparently, crucial that the key-files are created within the bind-directory `/etc/bind/`or the signing will not work.

There are also several ways to add the key-files to the zone-file but the one I finally got working was by using `$INCLUDE` inside the zone-file.

I've spent hours on this and hopefully my answer will help someone in the future. We all learn something each day.

Comment: How about in a folder called /etc/bind/keys/ ? is that still within /etc/bind/ sufficiently? key-directory "/etc/bind/keys";

Answer (score 1):

So I can't leave a comment, but instead have to leave an answer on a 9-year old question. I think that's backwards, but I'm not here for the criticism of serverfault, I was here for a slightly different issue, but stumbled around here.

Requiring the keys saved in a specific location sounds like an conflict with apparmor settings. On Debian, look in `/etc/apparmor.d/` and `grep` for a file containing `/etc/bind`. You can either adjust where you're saving the keys or adjust the apparmor settings, but that's out of the scope of this question.